# Separability of the Normal Closure of a non finite extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Gotta solve this problem:

If $K|F$ is a separable field extension, must its normal closure $N|F$ be separable?

Read another answer and when $K|F$ is finite, the answer is yes and the problem is already solved by using the primitive element theorem.  Now this time $K|F$ is not necessarily finite, so I'm not quite sure if the result is still true.

What I thought is that if I take $\alpha \in N\setminus K$, I have two possibilities:

-$MinPol_F(\alpha)$ has other root $\alpha_1$ in $K$, so as $K|F$ is separable, and $MinPol_F(\alpha) = MinPol_F(\alpha_1)$ $\implies$ $MinPol_F(\alpha)$ is separable and so on the normal closure $N$ is separable.

-$MinPol_F(\alpha)$ doesn't have any roots in $K$.

In this second case, how can I tell if the polynomial $MinPol_F(\alpha)$ is separable? If it has no roots in $K$, I can't use the fact that $K|F$ is separable in any way... but neither I can say that ''we can't assure that this polynomial is separable so the normal closure is not necessarily separable".

Maybe this polynomial with no roots in K can't exist?? Or this is not a good approach?

Comment: Infinite unions of finite separable extensions are separable, and the normal closure of $K/F$ is the union of the normal closure of all finite subextensions (union means union of the generators, so the compositum). Thus it suffices to look at the finite extensions case where the normal closure is just the extension generated by all the conjugates of the generators.

Comment: @reuns many thanks :)